# Java and jdbc - exe runnable file

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I have made a simple java task to make query to Ms sql DB on windows, using jdbc library.
The program runs perfectly on my eclipse. I want to use it as an exe file (so I can send it to friend so he can use that as well). 
I made a jar (using the export option on eclipse) so he can execute it as an exe file on windows. The problem is when he runs the jar file on windows for some reason the results of the query are empty. I am not sure what exactly is the problem.
It's not on localhost. This is how I connect -

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://**.***.***.***;" +          "databaseName=&&&&&&&&;user=&&&&&&&&&&&;password=$$$$$$$$";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

This is the error I get - not sure how to handle it:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0
```

I have sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc4.jar files on that folder.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) You are conflicting terms of JAR and EXE 2) Is your JDBC URI pointed at the same database&table and you aren't running your code against localhost or something?

Comment: Any exceptions? Are you logging stuff anywhere? My guess would be that you are not handling exceptions properly and your problem is getting unnoticed causing your program to nit function as expected. Would appreciate if you give us more code to look at.

Comment: I will post it soon. I choose on export to contain all the jars I am using, but still I get an error when exporting it - 'Jar export with warnings'. 
Maybe the jdbc jar is not included in the final jar file?

Comment: This is the error I get - not sure how to handle it:

     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime     Environment     (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use     the sqljdbc4.jar class     library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0

Comment: _"I have sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc4.jar files on that folder."_ what do you mean with this, you can't have two of these as they have the same name. If instead you have both `sqljdbc.jar` **and** `sqljdbc4.jar`, you need to remove `sqljdbc.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to modify your program so that it captures and prints out all runtime errors and warnings.

It also sounds like you want to add a "check health" feature to verify:

1. the program runs on your friend's PC,
2. the program connects to the MSSQL server,
3. the expected database is found on the server, and
4. the expected data exists in the database.

==================================================

ADDENDUM:

Thank you for updating your post and sharing the *real* problem:

> This is the error I get - not sure how to handle it:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment
>   (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the
>   sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0

It sounds like you compiled on an older version of Java (that's fine), with an older MSSQL/JDBC driver (that's fine, too) ...

... but your friend has a *NEW* JRE 1.8 which won't work with the new driver.

TWO SOLUTIONS:

1. Have your friend uninstall his JRE and then do a clean install of your Java version.  For example, you can find older JRE 1.7 here:

   - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html
2. Update your MSSQL driver to a current version (sqljdbc 4.2 is a good choice), verify that it works for you, then have your friend install the same MSSQL driver.  You can download it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484311%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

PS:
A third option - perhaps *best* - is for *both* of you to install the *same* version of Java and the *same* version of the MSSQL JDBC driver.

PPS: In the future, if you have an error message, please copy/paste it verbatim in your original post.  A good error message is very often enough to resolve the problem immediately.

Comment: I don't think uninstalling Java 8 should be a path to solve the problem. Java 7 can be installed on the side  then used to execute the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I just tried to run it as exe on my computer and got the exact same error...